Hidden Elements due to dynamic block property "Visibility" in BlockTableRecord
I am trying to determine which elements in a BlockReference are hidden due to a dynamic property in a BlockTableRecord.
BlockTableRecord blockRec = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blockRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);
foreach (ObjectId attDefId in blockRec)
{
}



I can't find the property in the BricsCAD object which defines if the object is hidden or not.
